# Error parsing unicode with HTMLParser

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

Here is my code which I'm running for Python 3.3:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class TableParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.in_table = False
        self.in_table_header = False
        self.in_table_header_field = False
        self.table_fields = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attributes):
        if tag == 'table':
            for name, value in attributes:
                if name == 'id' and value == 'data_table':
                    self.in_table = True
        if self.in_table == True:
            if tag == 'thead':
                self.in_table_header = True
        if self.in_table_header == True and tag == 'th':
            self.in_table_header_field = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'table':
            self.in_table = False
        if tag == 'thead':
            self.in_table_header = False
        if tag == 'th':
            self.in_table_header_field = False            

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_table_header_field == True:
            self.table_fields.append(data)

parser = TableParser()
parser.feed('<table id="data_table"><thead><tr><th>Company</th><th>Rapport</th><th>Price</th><th>Development 1&#229;r</th></thead></table>')
print(parser.table_fields)
```

Here is the output:

```
['Company', 'Rapport', 'Price', 'Development 1', 'r']
```

and I was expecting:

```
['Company', 'Rapport', 'Price', 'Development 1&#229;r']
```

or better still:

```
['Company', 'Rapport', 'Price', 'Development 1år']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a handler for the [`HTMLParser.handle_charref()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.handle_charref) as well:

```
def handle_charref(self, name):
    self.handle_data(self.unescape('&#{};'.format(name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring('<table id="data_table"><thead><tr><th>Company</th><th>Rapport</th><th>Price</th><th>Development 1&#229;r</th></thead></table>') 
>>> root.xpath('.//thead//th/text()')
['Company', 'Rapport', 'Price', 'Development 1år']
```